# Last import in Address Book

Tags: data-synchronization, contacts

A little history: I had a old Nokia 5310. Lost it. I had the contacts backed up in a .vcf file. So imported them to a old Sony Ericsson W700i. Used the W700i for sometime, added some more contacts.
Not got a new Nokia C5. Wanted to import all the contacts to the Nokia and at the same time add them to `Address Book` so that I can manage all contacts from `Address Book` and sync with the new Nokia. (`Address Book` has some old contacts, that are not required to be on the phone but nevertheless necessary, my wife's contacts imported sometime before etc). (Thanks for reading)

I exported the contacts from the phone to a .vcf file and imported it in Address Book.
Wanted to move only these contacts to the Nokia. So thought will open `Last Import` and sync all of them with the new phone.
But looks like `Last Import` holds all of my imports, not just the most recent one.

I tried to select a group and then import, but the import does not happen to the group. They are imported to the "All Contacts".

Is there any way to get/select only the most recent imported contacts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A smart group with a rule of "card was updated after (date)" would get you close to the correct list.  Also, in Lion, Last Import resets the list correctly for each import performed.

Comment: Is the date updated still available for smart groups? I hope it is still available to Applescripts. It seems missing from the app's interface.

Comment: "Card was updated after (date)" smart group rules are still available in Lion.

Answer (score 1):

Are you comfortable with AppleScript? If so, you could write a script to export the contacts created after a date of your choosing.

Comment: G. I am not very comfortable with AppleScript but have no problems learning. But will getting _contacts created after a date of your choosing_ be sufficient? It is possible that one of the contacts I imported last was already there and I had _merged_ it.

Comment: @Nivas you can also use the date it was last modified.